# Using controls in C#.net GUI Application

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface

How to control the input to the text box using vertical scroll bar control, the input to the text box is age which are numbers in a C# GUI application to design a windows form?

Comment: I think you are looking for the combobox control

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Here is my question as it is in the exercise book. The age text box should be disabled. The input to the age text box should be controlled by a vertical scroll bar control. So, there should be 2 controls, text box and vertical scrollbar.I think an event should be raised on the click of vertical scroll bar and add code to it, but I am not sure about the coding...so please help.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [Numeric UpDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.aspx) control.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Here is my question as it is in the exercise book. The age text box should be disabled. The input to the age text box should be controlled by a vertical scroll bar control. So, there should be 2 controls, text box and vertical scrollbar.I think an event should be raised on the click of vertical scroll bar and add code to it, but I am not sure about the coding...so please help.